# What regions do Red Beacons/Supply Caches usually appear in?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

What regions do Red Beacons/Supply Caches usually appear in?

Is it just random/rare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location of the beacons is fixed and each position has a range of colors the beacon can be. Not all colors are possible everywhere, see [this map](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Beacon_Locations) for the possible colors at each location. Higher quality drops are rarer than lower quality drops, though, so a location with a red-mark does mostly spawn non-red drops. Some drops also trigger the spawning of creatures like a rex in the area.

[image]

Comment: Great info, but do you have a source for "Some drops also trigger the spawning of creatures like a rex"? I hadn't heard this before.

Comment: @Angzuril: While I took the data of the beacon-locations and colors from the devkit I noticed a property called "TriggerSpawn" (or similar). Some drop-locations had for this property the value "Rex". I don't know if the game uses this property and actually does spawn a rex and with which probability, though.

Answer (score 1):

According to the gamepedia entry for [ARK](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Beacon), beacons have set spawn locations but any color can spawn at a given beacon spawn location. You're going to have to rely on luck if you're gunning for a specific color.

Comment: This is right.  You will notice certain spots will have multiple supply caches, but the color is random.  Red caches are uncommon, so they don't appear that often (it could just be because of RNG and the amount of colors).  Also @Enigma, i would edit your question to include the term Supply Cache or Supply Drop, because in-game it's referred to as a Supply Cache.  It should help prevent confusion.  Up to you, but just a suggestion.

Comment: That info on the wiki was wrong. Each position has a fixed set of possible colors (see my answer).

Comment: I was going to suggest updating the entry on the wiki as well but it seems you've already done that; Nice job!